# How do I clear images and data from previous runs in Python?

Tags: python, image, spyder

Disclaimer: I am new to Python and I have the latest Anaconda-Python (3.8.3) installed in my computer. My code is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import imageio
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    plt.clf()


    pic = imageio.imread('Photo_Vikash_pandey.jpg')
    plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))

    plt.imshow(pic)
```

Every time I run the code I see images piled up in the adjoining window of Spyder IDE. I want that every time I run the code, it has no history of its previous execution. I do not wish to see image display from previous runs of the code.

Comment: Would calling `plt.clf()` suffice?

Comment: You posted the same in your question.

Comment: Sorry @MarcinOrlowski, please see my question again.

Comment: This is a question about Spyder, not about Python. If you run your code from the shell using `python file.py`, you run the script in a new environment every time and no Windows will persist from run to run. Therefore, it is the Spyder environment that you use that preserves these windows.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it, Cris.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You can restart the kernel (i.e. the external process that executes your code in the console) before every run. You can do that by pressing the `Ctrl+.` keyboard shortcut while your focus is in the console.